# Truffle & TestRPC: how to use another address for transaction / sendTransaction Function parameters

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation

I have a Smart Contract, created / migrated with Truffle to TestRPC. TestRPC provides several default accounts. If I call functions within the Smart Contract from the Truffle console it does that always from the same address, even if when I set `web3.eth.defaultAccount = 'anotherAddress';`.

What I want is to be able to call functions from different addresses provided by TestRPC. How can I achieve that?

And if I want to use `web3.eth.sendTransaction`, where I can specify `from` and `to` how do I specify the parameters of the function?

Thanks

Comment: instance2.b_fun1(a_address)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass `options` object as a last argument of contracts method.

```
contractInstance.someMethod(arg1, arg2, { from: 'someAddress' });
```